# UICollectionView header/footer reference size crash

Tags: ios6, uicollectionview

I am struggling with the following issue. I have a UICollectionView that has its layout's header and footer reference sizes set to a value (say 40.0). When I remove/insert cell and the collection view is at a position such that the header and footer are not onscreen everything is fine. However, when they are onscreen upon doing the same actions my code crashes with the following error:

```
2012-12-17 16:05:05.042 BambooV2Demo[37770:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: <_UICollectionViewItemKey: 0x1e04cf70> Type = SV Kind = UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader IndexPath = <NSIndexPath 0x1e04fe90> 2 indexes [0, 0])'
```

On the other hand if I set the header and footer sizes to be 0.0 everything is perfectly fine again. Does anyone have an idea for the reasons for the crash when the header/footer size is different from zero and they are visible on screen?

Comment: I manage to do a workaround for the issue but it involves changing the layout to one with zero size header and footer, performing the operations for adding and deleting cells and setting the layout with the proper header and footer again. However there should be some kind of a reasonable explanation to why the crash occurs.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this issue when I had set a header size, but without specifying a view for the header.  Instead, I used the section insets and set the header size back to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You should return YES in the Method below in your Layout Subclass or via the delegate, which will cause a rearranging of the CollectionView Items to your layout.

```
- (BOOL) shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
    return YES;
}
```